# Convergence glmer() warnings

Tags: r, statistics, logistic-regression, lme4, analyzer

I have a little convergence concerns for one of my models, the data are in file attached: https://mon-partage.fr/f/06LTiBGt/
. To explain the data a little, it is a matter of knowing whether the formation of the pre-nymphs is impacted by the different modalities. The obs column corresponds to formed / unformed nymph. The day variables are very important in the model. I would like to use at least the hive variable as a random effect.
I tried to add to the function the bobyqa control, but the problem of convergence persists and follow the ?convergence. But alls optmizers converge C

Can i considers that it's false positive ?

Thank you in advance,

```
library("lme4", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.3")
> glmpn<-glmer(Obs~moda*jour+1|ruch)+1|code_test),data=dataall_pn,family=binomial(logit),glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa"))

Warning message:
In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.0054486 (tol = 0.001, component 1)
> summary(glmpn)
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: Obs ~ moda * jour + (1 | ruch) + (1 | code_test)
   Data: dataall_pn
Control: glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa")

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
 22477.2  22651.2 -11216.6  22433.2    20072 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-8.4511 -0.9370  0.4435  0.6890  1.5559 

Random effects:
 Groups    Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 ruch      (Intercept) 0.2811   0.5302  
 code_test (Intercept) 0.2475   0.4975  
Number of obs: 20094, groups:  ruch, 7; code_test, 5

Fixed effects:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  -3.47806    0.46287  -7.514 5.73e-14 ***
modaA         0.46866    0.50489   0.928 0.353281    
modaL        -2.77363    0.75599  -3.669 0.000244 ***
modaLA        2.04869    0.52218   3.923 8.73e-05 ***
modaP         2.19098    0.48984   4.473 7.72e-06 ***
modaB         1.75376    0.49874   3.516 0.000437 ***
modaBP        2.27875    0.52120   4.372 1.23e-05 ***
modaPL        2.01771    0.48696   4.143 3.42e-05 ***
modaBL        1.06337    0.48795   2.179 0.029312 *  
modaBLP       1.93218    0.51939   3.720 0.000199 ***
jour          0.41973    0.02981  14.079  < 2e-16 ***
modaA:jour   -0.06559    0.04188  -1.566 0.117369    
modaL:jour    0.19876    0.06491   3.062 0.002198 ** 
modaLA:jour  -0.22419    0.04267  -5.254 1.49e-07 ***
modaP:jour   -0.25363    0.04012  -6.322 2.58e-10 ***
modaB:jour   -0.19555    0.04097  -4.773 1.82e-06 ***
modaBP:jour  -0.23478    0.04262  -5.509 3.61e-08 ***
modaPL:jour  -0.24454    0.03988  -6.131 8.71e-10 ***
modaBL:jour  -0.16590    0.04003  -4.145 3.40e-05 ***
modaBLP:jour -0.21726    0.04245  -5.119 3.08e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
Correlation matrix not shown by default, as p = 20 > 12.
Use print(x, correlation=TRUE)  or
    vcov(x)    if you need it

convergence code: 0
Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.0054486 (tol = 0.001, component 1)
```

Comment: `help("convergence")`

Comment: Maybe try an increase the number of iterations. Also more info at `?convergence`

Comment: If i center and scale predictors with :  
## 1. center and scale predictors:
ss.CS <- transform(data, jour=scale(jour))
fm1.CS <- update(fm1, data=ss.CS)

it work.. but i'm sure of this model, AIC are really big.. 
Thank's !

Comment: The aic on its own doesnt really tell much - you could use it to compare two models, say after omitting one variable. Also the examples in `convergence` has a function `allFit` to run several optimizers - you could see if the solution is fairly consistent across these